# cmd running programmes sequentially

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am attempting to run a command line programme a number of times, each time from a separate folder which includes a different set of inputs.

I have the code:

```
cmd < run.in
```

Which inside it has:

```
cd .\1
..\..\fdtd.exe < input.in
cd ..\2
..\..\fdtd.exe < input.in
```

Which I thought should change to the input file directory, then run the programme with the input file. Once it has done, move to the next directory and run the programme again with the input file from that folder.

Instead the first one runs fine, then the second one just comes up with an output:
C:..\1>More?
But if I type the commands in the same order myself it runs correctly. I don't know whether the output is coming from cmd itself, or the fdtd.exe programme (the manual of which doesn't mention this as an issue).

Is the input file attempting to start the next command before the programme has finished shutting down and therefore cannot stop, or is there something inherently wrong with the way I am attempting to get the batch input files to work?

Thanks for the help,

Kieren

Comment: If fdtd.exe is a console app, it shouldn't be returning until it's exited. However, just in case you can use `start /wait ..\..\fdtd.exe < input.in` instead.

Comment: Try adding a line with `pwd` after every line of the script so you can see where it is currently running.

Comment: I attempted the start /wait ..\..\fdtd.exe < input.in but the input.in wasn't accepted, it just opened the programme and waited for a user input.
Adding the PWD after every line has apparently made it work, it still comes up with "More?" but does actually run every programme. Thanks for the help, even if I don't really understand why that has made any difference.

Comment: Does each instance of `input.in` end with a line break?  It sounds like perhaps not.  Adding a trailing line break at the end of each `input.in` will probably fix it.